# Pic32MZ - ADC/Multiplexing?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, analog, multiplexer

Using PIC32MZ2048EFH144 MCU.

Datasheet: http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/60001320D.pdf

12 Bit ADC

The board has 8 DMA Channels(Programmable/Dedicated). I am interfacing 10 microphones, therefore i need 10 channels to connect my analog microphones.

How do I connect two analog microphones to one port on my board. Multiplexing? How so...? Any references you guys have?

Comment: It depends on your specs for Bandpass range, Nyquist prefiltering attenuation, SNR, THD, Dynamic range needed, and output requirements.

Comment: @TonyStewart.EEsince'75 Okay, but how would I connect them physically to the board, regardless of specifications of my end results. How would I connect two microphones to one channel.

Comment: There are lots of analog channels, already, but you need to condition the signal with an amplifier.

Comment: That microcontroller has 48 ADC inputs, according to the datasheet.  Are you working with the microcontroller itself, or with a development board using that microcontroller?